# OleDb Update sql with Parameter value not updating record in Access

Tags: c#, oledb

Can anybody tell what is wrong in the following code ?

```
command.Connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
command.CommandText = "Update Table1 SET Replaceme = ? WHERE Searchme = ?";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Replaceme", "Goodman");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Searchme", "Anand");

command.Connection.Open();
int recordsaffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Records affected : " + recordsaffected);
```

`MessageBox` shows 0 records and it is actually not updating the record which is available.

Table name `(Table1)` and Column names `(Replaceme and Searchme)` are correctly spelled.

Comment: Lol at all the SQL Server developers posting answers who don't use System.Data.OleDb

Comment: Is there a row with "Anand" in the Searchme column? Are you looking at the right database? I.e. it's the one specified in the connection string. Do you have a transaction that you're not committing?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Hey Mr. know-it-all. Give your solution.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It's not "Know-it-all" it's "know-the-fundamentals".

Comment: What is the datatype of Searchme  column, is it fixed length or variable?

Comment: Anand row is there in DB. Anway, I found the solution. The complete story is OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(); is missing here. Meaning in single 'command' was earlier used by me for SELECT query. Now instantiated another variable of OleDbCommand named 'cmd' and now its working. Thanks guys & sorry for taking your valuable time. But let me tell you that the above code without using @ is a working one

Comment: @Anand Ignore the code that uses named parameters ("@") -- the members haven't read the Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I've used both approaches(named[sort of] and positional) multiple times with the OleDBCommand object that he uses and I've had no problems with either approach. As long as you add the parameters in the order they appear in the SQL then using `?` or `@ParaName` should work fine.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien Were you using JET or ACE by any chance? Because I think you'll find arbitrary Ole Db providers support positional parameters. If one or two support named parameters-but-not-really-they-have-to-be-in-order that doesn't mean it's okay to use them.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: isn't `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` one of the most common providers? I did make the assumption that he was talking about connecting to Access though so that was my mistake.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien It is, unfortunately, very common.

Answer (score 6):

First off, `OleDbParameter`s are positional, not named. Read the *Remarks* section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter). Disregard any answer that does not understand this.

Here's a minimal, working example.

First, create your database:

[image]

[image]

Second, write the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
            connectionString += "Data Source=C:\\Temp\\Database1.mdb";

            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE Table1 SET Replaceme = ? WHERE Searchme = ?";

                var p1 = command.CreateParameter();
                p1.Value = "Goodman";
                command.Parameters.Add(p1);

                var p2 = command.CreateParameter();
                p2.Value = "Anand";
                command.Parameters.Add(p2);

                var result = String.Format("Records affected: {0}",
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery());
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. The solution you have given too works for me

Comment: @Anand No problems. The effort was nothing, I felt bad about all the misinformation being posted as "answers". Glad it works!

Comment: What I got from this answer, which also helped solve my problem with Ole Db, was that you cannot use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('p1','p1value');` which implies named variables. So I concluded that one should use `?` in the query for value and then set values in order that they appear in the query.

Answer (score -1):

Its not working because you are using ? instead of @ for the parametrized query.

Use this and it should work:

`Update Table1 SET Replaceme = @Replaceme WHERE Searchme = @Searchme`

Comment: See remarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter