# Insert function to MS Access DB

Tags: c#

Am new to C# and need help for my project. 
Please assist!

I want to create a insert function which allows me to insert data into my MS Access DB.
However, i keep getting a error stating that missing semicolon (;) at the end of statement and the data won't be ended

Below is my code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Insert
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    OleDbConnection vcon= new  OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C://Database//HelloDB.accdb");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vcon.Open();

    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ab = string.Format("insert into Hello values(id, 'Hname'))", int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
        OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(ab, vcon);
        vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data stored successfully");
        vcom.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this line sticks out at me:

```
string ab = string.Format("insert into Hello values(id, 'Hname'))", int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
```

I believe it should read:

```
                                                            /*!*/
string ab = string.Format("insert into Hello values({0}, '{1}')", int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
```

Second, you should use parameterised SQL for this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12226939/242520) is an example I wrote to demonstrate how to use parameterised SQL for `UPDATE` statements. The code is mostly applicable to other statement types, like `SELECT` or `INSERT`.

Although, really, you should evaluate your use of JET/ACE for data access. JET comes with Windows, but ACE does not. So in your code you have a dependency on ACE. Consider if it would be better to have a dependency on SQL Server LocalDB, instead.

Comment: Okay, um, i followed what you said and removed the additional bracket on the line. However, i got another error saying OleDBException was unhandled - No value given for one or more required parameters. What's causing this? The values won't be inserted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with following:

string ab = string.Format( "insert into Hello values({0}, '{1}')", int.Parse( textBox1.Text ), textBox2.Text );